# Subdivision surfaces

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface

I am working with subdivision surfaces.
I removed some faces from object.
Then it created weird vertices like this image.
How can i fix that.

[image]

This is my blender file.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an ngon, it triangulates badly, you can fix that with the following topology:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how to do it.
I am new in blender.

Comment: You can either select 2 opposite vertices and press J, or remove the whole face, select the top edge, press F several times until it fills the hole

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: By the way, the Subdivision Surface modifier level is pretty high, you don't need such a high level, unless you plan to 3D print?